# Backbone model - collection property not empty on new model creation

Tags: backbone.js

I have a model with a backbone collection as an attribute. When I create a new model and save it along with its collection to the database it all works fine.

However, when I create a new model, its collection contains the previous models values. All the other properties are blank as expected.

I've defined my model defaults like this:

```
defaults: {
        InsertionOrderNumber: null,
        ClientID: null,
        CampaignName: null,
        FromDate: null,
        ToDate: null,
        TotalBudget: null,
        ManagementFee: null,
        AgencyCommission: null,
        SourceDocuments: new Uploads() //this is the collection
    }
```

For some reason it seems like the same instance of the collection is being used for all new models of that type.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is, `new Uploads()` is evaluated when you define your model, not when you create a new instance. Use a function to create new collections in the defaults:

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return {
            InsertionOrderNumber: null,
            ClientID: null,
            CampaignName: null,
            FromDate: null,
            ToDate: null,
            TotalBudget: null,
            ManagementFee: null,
            AgencyCommission: null,
            SourceDocuments: new Uploads()
        };
    }
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/gzTgt/

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for the quick response. Problem solved. I suspected it was something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks for identifying the problem, I was suffering from the exact same thing as I'm trying to learn Backbone. Once I understood what I was doing wrong, though, I felt like a better solution was to `this.set('SourceDocuments', new Uploads())` in the initialize function. Is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: @davidreedernst Nothing wrong per se, but 1. you'll have to check if you're not passing that attribute as an option to the constructor, and 2. be careful if you're setting listeners in your initialize function before the `set`, you'll trigger them. Side note : I prefer setting sub collections as `model.SourceDocuments` and not have them in the attributes